# C# delegate not bound to an instance?

Tags: c#

Is there a way to store a delegate without binding it to an object like how you can with a MethodInfo? Right now I am storing a MethodInfo so I can give it the object to call the method for. But I much rather have it be a delegate. Like is there an attribute that tells .net that the first parameter is "this"?

```
MethodInfo mi;
Action<string> func;
mi.Invoke(this,new object[]{str});
func(this, str); //Is this possible with a delegate?
```

Comment: could you rephrase the question with little more details, I think I got it partially but not sure.

Comment: Added an example of what I mean. Basically is it possible to have a delegate without an object reference and give it an object when you call it?

Comment: I changed the title of your question to make it clearer. Feel free to roll back if you don't like it ;)

Comment: Thanks, wasn't sure how to phrase a question like this.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

What you want is called an [open instance delegate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/96b1ayy4.aspx#Anchor_1). It isn't supported directly in the C# language, but the CLR supports it.

Basically, an open instance delegate is the same as a normal delegate, but it takes an extra parameter for `this` before the normal parameters, and has a null target (like a delegate for a static method). For instance, the open instance equivalent of `Action<T>` would be:

```
delegate void OpenAction<TThis, T>(TThis @this, T arg);
```

Here's a complete example:

```
void Main()
{
    MethodInfo sayHelloMethod = typeof(Person).GetMethod("SayHello");
    OpenAction<Person, string> action =
        (OpenAction<Person, string>)
            Delegate.CreateDelegate(
                typeof(OpenAction<Person, string>),
                null,
                sayHelloMethod);

    Person joe = new Person { Name = "Joe" };
    action(joe, "Jack"); // Prints "Hello Jack, my name is Joe"
}

delegate void OpenAction<TThis, T>(TThis @this, T arg);

class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public void SayHello(string name)
    {
        Console.WriteLine ("Hi {0}, my name is {1}", name, this.Name);
    }
}
```

Have a look at [this article](http://www.simple-talk.com/community/blogs/simonc/archive/2010/07/28/93676.aspx) for more details.

Comment: Shame that C# doesn't directly support it. Thanks for the info :D.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `Delegate.CreateDelegate` method to create a strongly-typed delegate for a `MethodInfo`.

If you don't know the method's signature at compile-time, you can either create a `Func<...>` using Reflection, or create a lambda expression that invokes the `MethodInfo`:

```
MethodInfo methodInfo = ...;
object thisObj = ...;
Func<object[]> callMethod = args => methodInfo.Invoke(thisObj, args);
```

(This is called currying)

Note that this will still have the performance hit from reflection every time the delegate is called, unlike `Delegate.CreateDelegate`.

Answer (score 1):

A delegate is essentially just a `MethodInfo` (actually, a `MethodBase`) and an object reference, with some internal pointers for performance. So if you have a `MethodInfo`, you essentially have an unbound delegate.

Comment: Functionally, yes, it's roughly the same. But MethodInfo.Invoke is much slower than invoking a delegate...

Comment: @Thomas Levesque: Granted.  For repeated calls, performance can be improved by calling `Delegate.CreateDelegate()` to create a bound delegate, but I would guess that for a bind-call-discard, bind-call-discard pattern, it wouldn't provide any performance benefit.

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply

```
Action<T, string> unbound = (This, str) => This.Method(str);
```

so you can

```
unbound(instanceA, "hello");
unbound(instanceB, "world");
```

or even

```
Action<string> bound = str => unbound(instanceC, str);
```