# TaskCompletionSource represents the producer side of Task<TResult> unbound to a delegate, providing access to the consumer side?

Tags: c#, concurrency, task

From  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd449174.aspx,

> `TaskCompletionSource<TResult>` Class represents **the producer side of a `Task<TResult>` unbound to a delegate**, providing access to **the consumer side** through the Task property.

What do the following mean:

1. the "producer"  sides of a `Task<TResult>`
2. the  "consumer" sides of a `Task<TResult>`
3. "unbound to a delegate"?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Producer would be the code that is producing the result,

```
public static class Math
{
    static int add(int a, int b)
    {
        return a + b;
    }
}
```

And you would be the consumer, the code that is calling into this class:

```
var result = Math.Add(2,3);
```

As for the unbound delegate, I think this is referred to as an open instance delegate, check out this [Delegate not bound to an instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5399273/c-sharp-delegate-not-bound-to-an-instance)